# Forcing a positive integer to be generated from ids.xml

Tags: android, android-permissions

Recently I've been getting into the habit of creating constants for request IDs within `res/values/ids.xml` to reduce clutter and ensure that each request is truly unique. For example, I may assign a custom ID to be [the request code for a `PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent[],%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)). However, I've just found out that I can't take this approach when handling a permission request.

Let's say I have this `ids.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <item name="permission_request" type="id" />
</resources>
```

When I then go to use this generated ID as part of my permission request:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE },
            R.id.permission_request);
```

I get an error message underlining the `requestCode` field:

> Value must be ≥ 0 (was -1100091)

I can potentially work around this by wrapping the ID in a `Math.abs()` call, but this seems a bit hacky. This also falls over if I try to check `requestCode` in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` using a `switch` statement as `Math.abs(R.id.permission_request)` is not a constant value.

So is there a way of ensuring that a value in `ids.xml` always returns a value greater than 0, or should I stick to the old-fashioned way and use a `private static final int` defined by myself for permission requests?

**EDIT** I realise now that `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is a normal-level permission that I don't need to ask the user for. However, the main question still stands.

Comment: can you use unsigned integers?

Comment: @YunusKulyyev That's what I'd like to know. IDs are generated as part of the build process so I have no say in what value it pumps out. I'd just like to ensure that value is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have documentation to back this up, but my understanding is that every aapt-generated resource id (not just `R.id` but any `R` inner class) begins with `0x7f`. The next two digits represent the subclass (`R.anim` is the first generated one, so its constants start with `0x7f01`, followed by `R.animator` with `0x7f02`, etc).

Anyway, the result of all this is that *every* generated `R.id` value will be negative.

I recommend just using old-school `static final` constants. If for some reason you gain value out of having these integers being a part of the resources system, you could use an integer resource:

```
<integer name="permission_request">100</integer>
```

But this means you need a `Context` instance so that you can call `context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.permission_request)` which I think is pretty burdensome.

Comment: `Anyway, the result of all this is that every generated R.id value will be negative.` - Interesting, I never realised that before. I suppose that since their original purpose for for identifying views within layouts, they weren't designed in mind for for other cases where a request code is required.

Comment: Ben is absolutely correct here. These resource IDs are always such great numbers as they have to be all unique, and are assigned in 'first come first serve' for AAPT1 and alphabetical order for AAPT2. For Michael's purpose the integer resource should be a good solution.